# What's the error on my anonymous ftp server? The upload works, the read not

Tags: ftp

I want to create an anonymous ftp. The user can upload and read only from pub directory.
The OS is Unixware 71, the ftp server is WU-FTPD.
This is the ftpaccess file

```
#ident  "@(#)unixsrc:usr/src/common/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.sbin/in.ftpd/ftpaccess /main/1"
#
# ftpd configuration file, see ftpaccess(4tcp).
#
loginfails      3
passwd-check    trivial         warn
class           all             anonymous,guest,real    *
compress        yes             all
tar             yes             all
readme          README*         login   all
readme          README*         cwd=*   all

#banner         /var/ftp/banner.msg
#message        /var/ftp/welcome.msg    login   all
#message        .message                cwd=*   all

#chmod          no              anonymous
delete          yes             anonymous,guest
#overwrite      no              anonymous,guest
#rename         no              anonymous,guest
#umask          no              anonymous

#limit          all      5      Wk0900-1800             /var/ftp/toomany.msg
#limit          all     20      SaSu|Any1800-0900       /var/ftp/toomany.msg

log             commands        anonymous,guest,real
log             transfers       anonymous,guest,real    inbound,outbound

#path-filter    anonymous,guest /var/ftp/filename.msg   ^[[:alnum:]-._]*$ ^[.-]

#upload         /home/ftp       *               no nodirs
#upload         /home/ftp       /pub/incoming   yes ftp other 0444 nodirs
upload          /home/ftp       /pub            yes ftp other 0755
```

This are the directories with permissions and owners of home/ftp

```
  1737    0 dr-xr-xr-x   5 root     root           96 Mar 29 03:44 /home/ftp/
 41212    0 d--x--x--x   2 root     root           96 Mar 29 03:19 /home/ftp/bin
 41215   20 ---x--x--x   1 root     sys         19904 Mar 29 03:19 /home/ftp/bin/ls
 41214    0 d--x--x--x   2 root     root           96 Mar 29 03:39 /home/ftp/etc
 41216    2 -r--r--r--   1 root     sys            33 Mar 29 03:36 /home/ftp/etc/passwd
 41217    2 -r--r--r--   1 root     sys            10 Mar 29 03:39 /home/ftp/etc/group
 41219    0 drwxrwxrwt   2 root     sys            96 Mar 29 03:44 /home/ftp/pub
 41218    2 -rwxr-xr-x   1 ftp      other         389 Mar 29 03:44 /home/ftp/pub/cast
```

The server works, I can upload the file "cast" on server as anonymous.
But as you can see, is not possible to read (is possible to get if you know the name of the file)

```
ftp -n 192.168.0.133
Connected to 192.168.0.133 (192.168.0.133).
220 unixware1 FTP server (Version wu-2.6.2(2) Wed Dec 21 20:49:51 EST 2005) ready.
ftp> user anonymous
331 Guest login ok, send your complete e-mail address as password.
Password: 
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
ftp> cd pub
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,133,245,145)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp> put cast
local: cast remote: cast
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,133,156,60)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for cast.
226 Transfer complete.
390 bytes sent in 2,5e-05 secs (15600,00 Kbytes/sec)
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,133,209,31)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp> ls cast
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,133,95,177)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found [on other forum](https://community.unix.com/t/error-on-ftp-with-anon-user/390532)
I had to copy a shared library in the chroot ftp.

```
mkdir -p /home/ftp/usr/lib
cp /usr/lib/libc.so.1 /home/ftp/usr/lib
```